# String format: getting u'' inside the final string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, format

I have a list of id's and I am trying the following below:

```
final = "ids: {}".format(tuple(id_list))
```

For some reason I am getting the following:

```
"ids: (u'213231231', u'weqewqqwe')
```

Could anyone help out on why the u is coming inside my final string. When I am trying the same in another environment, I get the output without the u''. Any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is unicode strings in python

for literal value of string  you can fist map with str

```
>>> final = "ids: {}".format(tuple(map(str, id_list)))

>>> final
"ids: ('213231231', 'weqewqqwe')
```